Как на Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS увеличить размер системного раздела (/dev/nvme0n1p3) за счет второго раздела(/dev/nvme0n1p4)?



Пробовал загружаться с LiveCD через Gparted уменьшать раздел (/dev/nvme0n1p4) получилось, но расширить (/dev/nvme0n1p3) он не даёт, только уменьшить. Подскажите пожалуйста что можно придумать?

они в таком порядке физически на блочном устройстве находятся? тогда после уменьшения второго надо его подвинуть вправо, чтобы освободилось место для увеличения первого.

На столь маленьком диске выпихивать /home отдельно от системного раздела наверно было плохой идеей

если диск c gpt разметкой, то уменьшаешь p4 в 2 раза. создавай новый раздел p5 на свободном месте, форматирешь его. копируй данные на него. потом удаляй p4. раздвигай p3. переносишь данные с p5 на p3. удаляй p5 и раздвигай p3 до конца.
о, на картинках есть ещё диски - копируй на них данные и сразу удаляй p4

А как можно быстро и безопасно перенести данные с одного раздела на другой???

tar или cp. ну tar.gz чуть побыстрее за счёт сжатия
